# bootstrap-tables onRefresh event not working

Tags: bootstrap-table

Any idea why the onRefresh event is not firing? First time through the table displays properly. But when clicking the refresh button it does not work (event does not fire). I thought this worked before, but I think a new version of bootstrap.min.js may have killed it (or perhaps it is just a coincidence). Any help would be helpful.

HTML:

```
<table id="stats-view-output4" data-pagination="false" data-show-refresh="true" data-search="false" 
               data-cache="false" data-show-toggle="false" data-show-columns="false"
               data-show-header="false" data-show-footer="false">
</table>
```

Javascript (a button gets u to this function):

```
function do_trader_instruments() {
  $('#stats-view-output4').bootstrapTable({
      onRefresh: function (params) {
          bpt_pie_chart();
      },
      columns: [{
          field: 'TradedInstruments',
          title: 'Traded Instruments'
      }],
      data: [{
          TradedInstruments: "<div id='instrument-chart'></div>"
      }]
  });
  bpt_pie_chart();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I gave up and did a brut force solution. Feels like a bug of a conflict somewhere. For anyone stumbling onto this here it is:

HTML:

```
        <div id="toolbar4">
            <div class="form-inline" role="form">
                <button id="refresh4" class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span></button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <table id="stats-view-output4" data-pagination="false" data-show-refresh="false" data-search="false" 
               data-cache="false" data-show-toggle="false" data-show-columns="false"
               data-toolbar="#toolbar4" data-toolbar-align="right"
               data-show-header="true" data-show-footer="false" style="font-size:11px;">
        </table>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function () {
    $('#refresh4').click(function () { 
        bpt_pie_chart();
    });
});

function do_trader_instruments() {
  $('#stats-view-output4').bootstrapTable({

    columns: [{
       field: 'TradedInstruments',
       title: 'Traded Instruments'
    }],
      data: [{
      TradedInstruments: "<div id='instrument-chart'></div>"
    }]
  });
  bpt_pie_chart();
}
```